# Handling of messages with several indicators

Tags: design, object-oriented

I am currently working on an application, which will show several messages (alarms - warnings - hints) on a cable-connected display.

As these messages depend on several indicators I have to decide when to show (one or more indicator fit) or to hide (no indicators fit) them. For the first implementation I use a sort of counter: if the counter is `== 0` the message is displayed, incrementing it (from any source) will hide it. As long as one source is against showing, it will hide. On the long run this will lead to the following problem:

At runtime I cannot see who switched a message off. Furthermore if the program size will increase, I can easily lose the point of whats going on.

I can imagine that this problem is rather common, so any ideas for a good implementation? The general framework for this is an embedded environment, using C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to handle this, but the easiest way is probably to use an Enumerator.  I'm a C# native, so I'll be using that but take a glance at [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t.aspx) which will let you see how to make an Enum work in C.

Effectively, an Enum is an ordered list of words that hide an Integer value, and are accessed using `EnumName.EnumValue` and can be used for a number of neat tricks from Dictionary keys to state-marking.  Even better, they're very cheap from a performance standpoint.

Let's take a crack at representing the four states you have at present (Alarm/Warning/Hint/Off) as an enum:

```
enum MessageState{ Off, Alarm, Warning, Hint}
```

Each message should be set up to require having one of these four values (I'd go so far as to default the value to Off) when they're sent over to the screen.  There, you'll use whatever method you want to determine who shows up - probably anyone without a MessageState equal to `MessageState.Off`.

You also can benefit from hiding some logging code in how you change this.  Take a chance and turn `MessageState` on the object to a `private` field.  This will force anyone that wants to change the `MessageState` to be one of those objects, or ask the object to change it.  When this value is changed, you can require the change-r (?) to tell you who they are.  That way, you can log who changed the message when:

```
private void ChangeMessageState(MessageState state, User user)
{ 
    //Do stuff here!
}
```